# Install x64(64-bit) and x86(32-bit) Microsoft Office on same pc?

Tags: microsoft-office

Can I have both versions of Microsoft Office on same Windows?  for example,
Office 2007 (32-bit) and Office 2013 (64-bit).

On answers.microsoft.com (the worst forum ever seen in my life) it was said, that's not possible.

Any ways?

Comment: [Microsoft says no](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/install-and-use-different-versions-of-office-on-the-same-pc-6ebb44ce-18a3-43f9-a187-b78c513788bf).

Comment: If horrible Microsoft's MSDN answers says **no** (as 90%+ cases I've seen) **StackExchange** always has answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The official line by Microsoft is that this is not possible.
The real answer is that it's possible but a bit complicated.

The simple solution is to install one of the versions in a virtual machine,
which might be too heavy.

In the article
[Installing 32bit and 64bit Office versions together](http://excelmatters.com/2013/08/30/installing-32bit-and-64bit-office-versions-together/),
the author was in contact with a Microsoft developer who gave the following rules
for the installation of multiple Office installations:

- Install the 64 bit versions first, from oldest to newest
- Then install any 32 bit versions, again in order of oldest to newest
- Do not try and install 32 and 64 bit versions of the same Office version
  (for example one should be version 2016 and the other 2013)
- Only have one version of Outlook installed.

If one of the versions refuses to activate, use the following commands:

```
cd  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office{number}"
cscript ospp.vbs /act
```

This article dates from 2013 and relates to Office 2013, so the solution
has still to be tested with the latest Office version.

Comment: I've tried this and confirm it worked. (installed 2010 x64 and 2007 x86 )

Comment: In my personal experience, that advice is still valid ten years later. Note that Office 2016, 2019, 2021 and 365 are all the *same* version internally (v16.0), so they can't be installed in parallel.